# Deploy Visual webpart with Asp.net custom server control

Tags: sharepoint, controls, wsp

I have created a Visual Web Part in WSP  builder project in VS2010. In this web part I have a ASP.net custom server control that exists in a project which I have  added to the solution.

Buy  when I add the web part to a web part page I get an exception that the assembly cannot be found. Can anyone guide me how can I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You wsp depends on another assembly in you solution, so you should add additional assembly in package file.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231595.aspx